# jQuery Cloud Zoom - Advance Images on large image click

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, zooming

I'm using the jQuery cloud zoom for an image gallery and have disabled the zoom (long story, but it's working). Right now, I have disabled clicking the large image.

I'm looking to advance the images (i.e. go to the next image) on *click of the large image*, rather than having to click the thumbnails to change the image.

Here's my example page:

http://future.thefutureforward.com/~field/Travel-Kit.html

Any thoughts?

Comment: I have no idea what you want... so enable cloud zoom on click of the large image? the id `product_thumbnail` is no thumbnail, but the full size. and if you want a zoom function on the large image, put an image in the `<a href="..` which is larger then the `img` which is currently in the `<a>` anchor tag.

Comment: Hi JP, I just re-worded my question above for a bit more clarity. I'm looking to advance the images (i.e. go to the next image) on click of the large image, rather than having to click the thumbnails to change the image.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I took the cloud zoom example and made a [jsfiddle working example](http://jsfiddle.net/FmstM/)

The jQuery code below works, the only minor 'bug' is when the last image is clicked, it does not go back to number one. But otherwise there is nothing more to do for you ;) lol

Please note that I have had to use the `live` method for binding the click event.

```
$(".mousetrap").live("click", function(){
    var current = $(this).prev().attr("href");
    var tmp = $("a.cloud-zoom-gallery[href='" + current + "']").next();

    if(tmp.length)
        tmp.click();
    else
    {
        alert($("a.cloud-zoom-gallery:first-child").html()); /* null?? */
        $("a.cloud-zoom-gallery:first-child").click();
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the help so far JP. It's getting closer on my end, I'm just running into a couple of issues - it doesn't work on initial page load, and then once you click a thumbnail and then click the large image, it goes right to the last image everytime - http://future.thefutureforward.com/~field/Carryall-Bag.html

Comment: Please take a look at the jsFiddle. There is the code working on page load and does not skip to the last image. Your codes probably does not work because of the extra `div` in the thumbnailarea.

Comment: ps. it would be better to have the thumbs in an unordered list `<ul>` with listitems `<li>` but if you do, the jQuery selectors change also. and since you do not have cloud zoom enabled, the mousetrap class is not created. so the code does not work. In order to get it to work, you need to enable the zoom function.

Comment: "Please note that I have had to use the live method for binding the click event."

I confirm that you have to use live() to bind and on() doesnt work.